# Compare multiple columns and create new ones in R

Tags: r, compare, multiple-columns, dplyr

I have a big dataset of measured data at the Start (A) and the end(B) in replicates. Now I want to sort my datarows into "appeared in the end"(appeard) and "still present"(present) and pass the data into new columns.

```
data<-data.frame(A1=c(1,2,4),
   A2=c(3,5,4),
   B1=c(10,0,5),
   B2=c(1,0,1))
```

Desired output:

```
data_res<-data.frame(A1=c(1,2,4,0),
                 A2=c(3,5,4,0),
                 B1=c(10,0,5,1),
                 B2=c(1,0,1,2),
                 appeared1=c(0,0,0,1),
                 appeared2=c(0,0,0,2),
                 present1=c(10,0,5,0),
                 present2=c(1,0,1,0))
```

As you can see, if the Data appeared in the end, I want the output of B in multiple columns, if not a zero should be passed. If the Data is still present, I need the output of B as well, if not a zero.
Thanks for help!

Comment: When the data goes in `appeared1`, `appeared2` as compared to `present1`, `present2` ?  Why all values are 0 for second row?

Comment: I guess the last row from appeared1 to present2 should be `0,0,1,2`, instead of `1,2,0,0`, am I right? Or what is the logic for your output?

Comment: Present and appeared are two different things. If it was present in the beginning, it did not appear, therefore Appear gets a 0. A2 compaired to B2 gets 0,0,0,2 because only the last row was not present in the begining. As I said A is the Star, B is the end and all of them have replilcates.

Comment: Can you include few more columns in the sample dataset and who how expected output would look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
data<-data.frame(A1=c(1,2,4,0),
                 A2=c(3,5,4,0),
                 B1=c(10,0,5,1),
                 B2=c(1,0,1,2))

out<- mutate(data, appeared1 = if_else(A1 == 0, if_else(B1 != 0, B1, 0), 0))
out<- mutate(out, appeared2 = if_else(A2 == 0, if_else(B2 != 0, B2, 0), 0))
out<- mutate(out, present1 = if_else(A1 != 0, if_else(B1 != 0, B1, 0), 0))
out<- mutate(out, present2 = if_else(A2 != 0, if_else(B2 != 0, B2, 0), 0))
```

Output:

```
> out
  A1 A2 B1 B2 appeared1 appeared2 present1 present2
1  1  3 10  1         0         0       10        1
2  2  5  0  0         0         0        0        0
3  4  4  5  1         0         0        5        1
4  0  0  1  2         1         2        0        0
```

If you have more columns you can use a for loop:

```
out <- data
for (i in 1:2){
  var1 = paste0('appeared',i)
  var2 = paste0('present',i)
  Ai <- paste0('A',i)
  Bi <- paste0('B',i)
  out<- mutate(out,  !!var1 := if_else( !!sym(Ai) == 0, if_else(!!sym(Bi) != 0, !!sym(Bi), 0), 0))
  out<- mutate(out, !!var2 := if_else(!!sym(Ai) != 0, if_else(!!sym(Bi)!= 0, !!sym(Bi), 0), 0))
}
```

Remember to change the range in the for loop based on the amount of replicates that you have.

Comment: Yes, this would work, but is there  a solution to combine all lines? My originial data has more columns. Thanks anyway :)